# Is it possible to open a page in selenium in headless mode and then if it returns a 200 status code to open it in normal window?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have made a program in python that opens many pages concurrently but I don't want to open a page until it returns status code 200. The program starts request in headless mode and then check if it returns status code nr 200. So if it returns status nr 200 I want it to open that exact request but now in normal chrome window. Is this possible and can you suggest to me any documentation or a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would personally use `request module` in **Python** to `verify the status code`.

if we get `200-OK` then I would **launch** `Selenium in GUI mode`.

### request module to check status code :

```
# import requests module
import requests
  
# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/')
  
# print response
print(response)
  
# print request status_code
print(response.status_code)
```

Now validate the same using if clause

```
if response.status_code == 200:
```

then launch the browser.

**Sample full code :**

```
# import requests module
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\***\\***\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe'
# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/')

# print response
print(response)

# print request status_code
print(response.status_code)

if response.status_code == 200:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
else:
    print('Status code returned was not 200 so do not do anything, or may be Pass ? ')
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for response.The problem is that i  make request only for one web address..When that web address returns 200 status i want to open that exact response and not make another request.The whole point is that i don't want to open lots of chrome windows to overload my machine.

Comment: With the solution that I have given above, there wouldn't be multiple chrome windows. Request is just to verify the status code,  it would not open nothing.